# Mockito @MockBean wont execute when on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

I'm super frustrated with a Kotlin/Mockito problem

What I want to accomplish is very simple, I've an AuthorizationFilter on my springboot application and for test purposes I want to mock its behavior to let the test requests pass by

My AuthorizationFilter indeed calls an API which will then provide the user auth status. so I thought that the simplest way to mock this is just have the AuthApi mocked into the filter and return whatever status I want... BUT IT WORKS RANDOMLY

```
@Component
class AuthorizationFilter(
    val authApi: authApi
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {
        if (request.method.equals("OPTIONS")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            return
        }

        val token = request.getHeader("authorization")

        if (token == null) {
            response.sendError(401)
            return
        }


        runCatching {
            authApi.authorize(token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
        }.onSuccess {
            AuthorizationContext.set(it)
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        }.onFailure {
            it.printStackTrace()
            response.sendError(401)
        }
    }
    
    }
```

the authApi authorize method is irrelevant to this question, but just let it be clear it will NEVER return null... it might throw an exception but wont return null

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SocketIOServerTest {
    @MockBean
    lateinit var mockedApiComponent: AuthApi


    @Autowired
    lateinit var boardRepository: BoardRepository


    @Autowired
    private lateinit var servletRegistrationBean: ServletRegistrationBean<SocketIOServer>
    private lateinit var socketIOServer: SocketIOServer

    @LocalServerPort
    private val serverPort: String? = null

    lateinit var clientSocket: Socket

    private val userId = 1
    private val groupId = 123
    private val admin = false
    private val auth = Authorization("token", userId, groupId, admin)

    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()


    @BeforeAll
    fun connect() {
        AuthorizationContext.set(auth)
        Mockito.`when`(mockedApiComponent.authorize(anyOrNull())).thenReturn(auth)

        socketIOServer = servletRegistrationBean.servlet

        clientSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:${serverPort}", IO.Options.builder().setExtraHeaders(mutableMapOf(Pair("Authorization", listOf("Bearer token")))).build())
        clientSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            println("client connected")

        }
        clientSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT) {
            println("client disconnected")
        }
        clientSocket.connect()
    }



    @Test
    fun testPingPong() {
        var finished = false
        clientSocket.on("pong") {
            println("event: ${it[0]}")
            val pongTime = (it[0] as String).substring(18, 31).toLong()
            assertTrue(System.currentTimeMillis() - pongTime < 1000)
            finished = true
        }
        clientSocket.emit("ping")

        while (!finished) Thread.yield()
    }

    @Test
    fun testBasicNotification(){

        clientSocket.on("basic_notification"){
            println(Arrays.toString(it))
        }

        socketIOServer.send(SocketIOEvent("${groupId}","basic_notification","data"))
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

    @Test
    fun testBoardNotification() {


        clientSocket.on("entity_create") {
            val event = it[0] as String
            println("event: $event")
            val eventValue = objectMapper.readValue(event, Map::class.java)
            val entityValue = eventValue["entity"] as Map<*, *>

            assertEquals("BOARD", eventValue["entity_type"])
            assertEquals("board name", entityValue["name"])
            assertEquals(groupId, entityValue["groupId"])

            assertEquals(userId, entityValue["created_by"])
            assertEquals(userId, entityValue["last_modified_by"])


        }

        val board = boardRepository.save(Board(groupId, "board name"))


        //boardRepository.delete(board)

    }}
```

Just to be clear, THE TEST WORKS, the assertions are correct and although it has some random behavior at the end it works.... BUT IT PRINTS A BIG STACK TRACE DUE SOME CRAZY BEHAVIOR

As you can see I'm using a SocketIO client which sends several requests out of my code... some of them get authenticated and some of them throw nullpointerexception on this line

```
.onSuccess {
                AuthorizationContext.set(it) //this line
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            }.
```

because `it` is null, because somehow the `mockedApiComponent.authorize()` returned null... again which would be impossible on the real component and which shouldn't be happening because the mock clearly states which object to return

I've exhaustively debbuged this code, thinking that somehow junit got two beans of the `AuthApi`
but the whole execution shows the same object id which matches the mock... and even weirder that the `token` parameter used on authorize is always the same

can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please post also the stack trace? It will definitely help to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I've exhaustively debbuged this code, thinking that somehow junit got two beans of the AuthApi but the whole execution shows the same object id which matches the mock... and even weirder that the token parameter used on authorize is always the same

This looks to me disturbing, like some problem with async code at runtime. I would try to do a couple of things:

1. Check for when the context is *null* in: `AuthorizationContext.set(it)` and put some more debug code to know what is happening. Or just debug from there
2. Use a `recover{}` block to deal with the *NullPointerException* and debug from there to see original problem in stack trace
3. What happens when instead `runCatching{}` you use `mapCatching{}`?